# Регулярное выражение в JS

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Привет. Не силён в регулярках. Пожалуйста, помогите оставить только `[A-z,0-9,-,_,%]` (большие и маленькие латинские символы, цифры, минус, нижнее подчёркивание, процент).

```
<a href="#$Hello-worls-link-117-page?">Hello</a>

$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);

    var $this = $(this);
    var href = $this.attr('href');
    var out = /* магия с регуляркой и href */

    console.log(out); // Hello-worls-link-117-page

});
```

Comment: @Олег Б, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что пробовали, что не получилось?

[Читали](http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+)?

Подсказки:

1. `var out = href.replace( что_меняем, на_что);`
2. `/[^xyz]+/` – регексп совпадет с любыми символами кроме x, y, z
3. `/[A-Z0-9%_-]+/` – регексп совпадет с вашими разрешёнными символами.

Дальше сами.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, вашей информации оказалось достаточно.